# Put custom Class in ApplicationDataContainer in C# (WinRT)

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, local-storage

I have a Windows 8 application. This application has several custom-defined classes. I need to store instances of these instances into Isolated Storage. From my understanding, Isolated Storage has been replaced with ApplicationDataContainer. Currently, I'm trying the following:

```
public class MyClass
{
  private HttpClient service = new HttpClient();

  public string FirstName { get; set; }

  public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }

  public int Gender { get; set; }

  public async Task Save()
  {
    // Do stuff...
  }
}

...

MyClass myInstance = new MyInstance();
// do stuff...

try {
  ApplicationDataContainer storage = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
  if (storage != null)
  {
    if (storage.Values.ContainsKey("MyKey"))
      storage.Values["MyKey"] = myInstance;
    else
      storage.Values.Add("MyKey", myInstance);
  }
} catch (Exception ex)
{
  MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Unable to save to isolated storage");
  dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

What am I missing. Why is an exception always being thrown. The exception is not very descriptive. Its just a generic System.Exception and the message doesn't help either.  Can someone please help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception I get from the code above seems pretty clear:

> Data of this type is not supported.

Per [Accessing app data with the Windows Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx#App_settings)

> The [Windows Runtime data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205768.aspx) are supported for app settings.
>
> Note that there is no binary type. If you need to store binary data, use an application file.

You can use the [ApplicationDataCompositeValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdatacompositevalue.aspx) class to group settings that must be treated atomically (but they still need to be supported runtime data types).  Scenario 4 of the [Application Data Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ApplicationData-sample-fb043eb2) covers this.

In your specific case though, you may want to consider serializing to a file and using [app file storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx#App_files) versus settings.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented my [ModelStorage](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ModelStorage) framework for this scenario.